# Failed to connect openshift using oc client on wsl2

Tags: windows, ubuntu, openshift, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am using wsl2 (Ubuntu) on windows, and I have been installed openshift client for windows, but when I run oc login (oc login https://myhost --token=myToken) on wls2, it returns "error: dial tcp: lookup "myhost" on xxx.xx.xxx.x:xx: read udp xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx->xxx.xx.xxx.x:xx: i/o timeout - verify you have provided the correct host and port and that the server is currently running."

Note: When i run oc login on windows (cmd/powershell) it works

Any solutions?

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

The problem is because I'm using vpn(GlobalProtect) when connecting to openshift. When I disconnect the vpn, the oc command runs properly.

Is it possible to run the oc command while connected to vpn (GlobalProtect)?

Comment: Where is `myhost`? It's not your `localhost`, correct? Can your WSL2 shell DNS resolve it and reach it at all, independent of `oc`? Try `dnslookup` and then `curl`.

Comment: ```myhost``` is my openshift server host, I've already updated my question, the problem is because I'm using vpn(GlobalProtect) when connecting to openshift. When I disconnect the vpn, the oc command runs properly. Is it possible to run the oc command while connected to vpn (GlobalProtect)?

Comment: So you don't need the VPN to reach `myhost`, but when the VPN is connected, Windows native can still reach `myhost`, but your WSL2 instance cannot, correct? Does it depend on whether the VPN was connected when you _started_ the WSL2 instance? But sounds like this is really a WSL/Windows/networking/VPN question. I'd do as much as you can to isolate the cases that work and fail, and you might need to tag the question differently or take it to a different support site.